# could not find function "knnImputation" in R

Tags: r, knn

I am getting error **could not find function "knnImputation"**

- **Rstudio version :-** Version 1.2.1335
- **loaded packages :-** c("ggplot2", "corrgram", "DMwR", "usdm", "caret", "randomForest", "e1071",
    "DataCombine", "doSNOW", "inTrees", "rpart.plot", "rpart",'MASS','xgboost','stats')

Comment: on which line of code are you getting this error?

Comment: Hello @abhilb i am getting error while imputing values on dataset
train=knnImputation(train, k = 181).

Comment: I assume you have added this line at beginning of your script ```require(DMwR)```

Comment: I tried the example at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DMwR/versions/0.4.1/topics/knnImputation and it works

Comment: @abhilb yes i have addes the require(DMwR) in beginning. and also tried with the link you provided, still no siuccess.

Comment: do you have multiple versions of R?

Comment: and does loaded packages ``` (.packages())``` list DMwR ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the VIM::kNN() imputation as the package DMwR has been removed from CRAN:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DMwR/index.html

```
# using DMwR::knnImputation
df_mod <- DMwR::knnImputation(df, k = 7)

# VIM approximate equivalent to DMwR
# Note, for numFun you can substitute stats::weighted.mean, they perform similarly, though some differences on the margins I am not sure of
df_mod <- VIM::kNN(df, k = 7, numFun = laeken::weightedMean, weightDist = TRUE)
```

I have had some challenges in some circumstances using DMwR::knnImputation, this appears to work well.